# Adding argument to an xlwings Python function makes it break down

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, xlwings

I am using xlwings to implement Python code in Excel. I put the following code in Spyder and imported it into Excel using xlwings to to perform a scipy optimization on 7-asset portfolio of financial assets

```
@xw.func
def risk_budget_objective_error(weights,*args):

    #Covariance table occupies the first position in args variable
    covariances = args[0]

    #State risk budgets
    assets_risk_budget = args[1]



    weights = np.matrix(weights)


    #Calculate portfolio st_dev
    portfolio_stdev = calculate_portfolio_risk(weights,covariances)

    #Calculate risk contributions
    assets_risk_contribution = calculate_risk_contribution(weights,covariances)

    #Calculate desired risk contribution of each asset
    assets_risk_target = np.multiply(portfolio_stdev,assets_risk_budget).astype(float)

    #Calculate error between desired contribution and calculated distribution of each asset
    squared_error = np.square(assets_risk_contribution-assets_risk_target.T)
    sse = sum(squared_error)

    return sse

@xw.func 
def erc_weights(covariances,assets_risk_budget, num_assets):

    #Constraints to optimization

    cons = ({'type':'eq','fun':lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1.5},
                  {'type':'ineq','fun':lambda x: x})

    bounds = ((0,.50),(0,None),(0,None),(0,None),(0,None),(0,.50),(0,None),(0,.10),(0,.25))

    init_weights = [.5]*num_assets

    #Optimization in scipy
    optimize_result = minimize(risk_budget_objective_error,
                               x0 = init_weights,
                               method = 'SLSQP',
                               args = (covariances, assets_risk_budget),
                               constraints = cons, 
                               options = {'disp':True,'ftol':1e-50}
                               )

    #Get optimized weights
    weights = optimize_result.x

    return weights
```

My issue is with the erc_weights function. I am trying to make it so that the number of assets in the portfolio is one of the arguments in the function.

In turn, I made num_assets an argument, which is the number of assets in the portfolio (edited code shown below) but every time I add it as an argument, the function breaks down and produces an error. To be clear, the only changes in the below code are the inclusion of num_assets as an argument and the change of the formula for init_weights to [.5]*num_assets

The same occurs when I try to make other parameters endogenous. eg: total weight cap, bounds etc, so any solution to this problem will definitely be of use in those areas as well. Thank you

```
@xw.func 
def erc_weights(covariances,assets_risk_budget, num_assets):

    #Constraints to optimization

    cons = ({'type':'eq','fun':lambda x: np.sum(x) - 1.5},
                  {'type':'ineq','fun':lambda x: x})

    bounds = ((0,.50),(0,None),(0,None),(0,None),(0,None),(0,.50),(0,None),(0,.10),(0,.25))

    init_weights = [.5]*num_assets

    #Optimization in scipy
    optimize_result = minimize(risk_budget_objective_error,
                               x0 = init_weights,
                               method = 'SLSQP',
                               args = (covariances, assets_risk_budget),
                               constraints = cons, 
                               options = {'disp':True,'ftol':1e-50}
                               )

    #Get optimized weights
    weights = optimize_result.x

    return weights
```